# D-Threose: reduction and optical activity

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates, optical-properties

I've bumped into this exercise:

> Judging by the mechanism of reaction between *D-threose* and $\ce{NaBH4}$, do you think the final product will be optically active?

To me looks like a reduction, since $\ce{NaBH4}$ is a lightly reductive agent, but then why the answer is "No, the product is not optically active"?

Is it because of the presence of anomers or there are other reasons?

Comment: I have edited your question to include the `ce` for chemical equations. For example, typing `$$\ce{2KClO3 ->[MnO2] 2KCl + 3O2}$$` will be rendered as: $$\ce{2KClO3 ->[MnO2] 2KCl + 3O2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you reduce the aldehyde (from the open chain threose, since the cycle cannot be reduced as it has only acetal-like functionality) you introduce a symmetry element (both ends of the molecule become $\ce{CH2OH}$).

The presence of a symmetry element means the reduced molecule is not chiral, but **meso**.